# Consuming secured ArcGIS for Server services in Google Earth?

Tags: arcgis-server, google-earth, security

I am able to easily consume unsecured ArcGIS for Server (AGS) services in Google Earth (GE), but not secured services.

I have created a KML Link in AGS Manager with no luck, and added the service manually as a link in GE with the same result.

The service is added to GE but a red circle is displayed when the service refreshes.

Has anyone been able to do this successfully?

Comment: do you have any ability in GE to specify a token or proxyURL for the secured service?

Answer (score 1):

According to the ESRI article "[FAQ: Can a secured KML service be displayed in Google Earth?](http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012923)", you cannot connect Google Earth to secure web services.

> No, a secured ArcGIS for Server Keyhole Markup Language (KML) service
>   cannot be displayed in Google Earth. Only KML services created from
>   unsecured map services are accessible in Google Earth.  Last Modified: 2/7/2017

Answer (score 0):

You can append the token to the link with the layers.

Example:
https://myserver:6443/arcgis/services///MyService/MapServer/KmlServer?Composite=false&compatibilityMode=GoogleEarth&LayerIDs=0&token=THE_TOKEN

To generate the token in the first place, you can go to:
https://myserver:6443/arcgis/tokens/generateToken

This is a bit brittle though.  In Google Earth 7.1, if you look at the properties of the Network Link and click Cancel, the token gets removed from the link with the layers.